# Count occurrences of each duplicate in a range and summarize in a list using a button

Tags: excel, vba

We're a big group of friends that are currently using Excel as a tool for documenting the usage of our shared instruments. At the moment we are manually adding our initials on the dates that we are using a specific instrument.

Since we are a big group and would like to review the usage on a weekly basis (rather than current monthly since it takes a lot of time for different members), we're wondering if there is a "Quality-of-life" solution to summarizing two aspects of the data.

Since it is not always the same person reviewing the usage, not everyone is as acquainted to using Excel (lots of older members that are having difficulties). As such we're wondering if it is possible to automate our tasks of summarizing the amount of occurring initials both as a total sum but also per instrument using a so called Macro button. If this is viable, then we'd adjust our range of dates from a monthly checkup to a weekly one which would make the instruments more readily available.

Since we're hesitant to acquire more instruments (due to this logistical fear of keeping up with documentation), it would be beneficial if there was a way to include the possibility of expanding the amount of instruments represented in the 2:nd row.

**Screenshots of our current setup using CountIf in Sheet2 using the data in Sheet1.**

Sheet1 and Sheet2, named "Instrument borrowing list" and "Monthly Summary" respectively.

[Sheet1/Instrument borrowing list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM51g.png)

[Sheet2/Monthly Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I5OQ.png)

***Our current list is setup as follows:***

On Sheet1 we have the following "headers":

**A1:** Month + Year

**A2:** Date (followed by the number of dates in that specific month below in A3->A# ((# representing the final date of the month)).

**B2->K2:** Each column on the 2:nd row represents an instrument (each row below each column being the space for filling out ones initials).

**B3->K#:** Represents the range for input of initials per date and instrument.

**A37:~** Represents the initials in alphabetic order followed by the full name.

On Sheet2 is where we, using CountIf function, summarize the amount of occurring initials.

So each member puts in their initials below the specific instrument that they're using on a specific date(s). Below that table is a legend representing each initials with their respective full name of the member. Currently we're using that as our Criteria in the CountIf function used in Monthly Summary.

So in Monthly Summary, to get the total usage of member "AaBb", we have

*=COUNTIF('Instrument borrowing list'!B3:K33;'Instrument borrowing list'!A37)*

And this comes back with the total amount of times that AaBb (with A37 as the criteria) occurs in the B3:K33 range. (i.e. across all instruments and dates). The same function is applied to get the total usage of a specific instrument by a member, but only referencing that specific column rather than the whole range of columns.

*=COUNTIF('Instrument borrowing list'!B3:B33;'Instrument borrowing list'!A37)*

This is very time consuming for us and older members are having issues with accomplishing it. The goal is to have this automated through the press of a single button, meaning that upon clicking a button in Instrument borrowing list, a table of initials is generated based on the legend from A37 and below, followed by the # of occurring times per specific column in Monthly Usage.

So the pressing of the button would essentially produce both the initials as well as the total # of occurring initials for respective column.

**Below is a screenshot of Sheet1 with a button assigned to performing the desired result displayed in Sheet2.**

[Sheet1/Instrument borrowing list with button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8CwJ.png)

So effectively what we're currently doing is that each member has access to a new excel file every month where they can input their initials for using the specific instruments on specific dates. At the beginning of a new month, the previous month is then summarized using CountIf function for each occurring initials, both as a whole across the whole range (from B3->P# ((P# being the final row on the final date of the month, for example if a month's final date is 30th then the range would be B3->P32)), but also per specific instrument.

We've tried looking into PivotTables and VBA but unfortunately we do not have programming experience to garner any success in achieving what we'd want, or if it is even possible to automate such a task using Excel. We're hoping that we could gain some insight and hopefully learn something new by asking for help here. If you have any resources that we should be looking into that might grant us an understanding of accomplishing this that would be lovely.

I hope that this provides enough information as to our desired result.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I recommend to provide a screenshot and/or example data for better understanding. And for that example data you should provide how your desired result would look like (do the calculations by hand, so it is easier to see what get's summed and counted). Reading [mcve] might help to improve your question.

Comment: Hi Pᴇʜ!

I will do that right away then and update my question with screenshots detailing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you know how to copy this code and link it to a button in your worksheet.

This Macro should do the trick. I am still learning so my code isn't the greatest but it should be effective. It works on the sample worksheet I tried it on.

The entire worksheet would need to be empty below the final date in column A (ie. remove everything below the last populated DATE VALUE in Column A) as it will populate a legend of initials and populate the sum of occurrence under each instrument.

Let me know what you think and if it works.

```
Sub Initial_Report()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim holder, initialLastRow, lastRow, lastRow2, x As Long

initialLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
holder = (ActiveSheet.Range("P1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count) + 1

For x = 66 To 80
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    lastRow2 = ActiveSheet.Range(Chr(x) & 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    ActiveSheet.Range(Chr(x) & 3 & ":" & Chr(x) & lastRow).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=ActiveSheet.Range("A" & lastRow + 1), _
        Unique:=False
Next

    lastRow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    With Range("A" & initialLastRow & ":A" & lastRow)
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        .Sort Key1:=Range("A" & initialLastRow), _
            Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    End With

    lastRow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    With Range("B" & initialLastRow)
        .Formula = "=COUNTIFS(B$3:B$" & (initialLastRow - 1) & ", $A" & initialLastRow & ":$A" & lastRow & ")"
        .AutoFill Destination:=Range("B" & initialLastRow & ":B" & lastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With

    With Range("B" & initialLastRow & ":B" & lastRow)
        .AutoFill Destination:=Range("B" & initialLastRow & ":P" & lastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With

    Rows(initialLastRow & ":" & initialLastRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    With Range("A" & initialLastRow)
        .Value = "Persons"
        .Style = "Accent1"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi again Abdul!

Thank you for the reply!

I have linked your macro to a button and ran it on my example worksheet (like the one in the pictures in the original post named "Instrument  borrowing list").

However upon clicking the button I received an error and it created a list of initials.

**Run-time error '1004': This can't be applied to the selected range. Select a single cell in a range and try again.**

Upon pressing debug, it highlights a section of the code. [Screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/8q9SgAz)

Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: It seems like your data is in a TABLE. I had assumed it wasn't a table when writing the macro - my mistake. Can you try to copy paste your data on a blank sheet as values (without being inside a Table) and run the macro? If that works we'll know what the problem with the macro is.

Comment: How it works is:
1) Copy data from columns B and paste in column A below the last cell in use. Repeat until Column P and keep pasting in Column A.
2) Remove duplicates in the pasted values in Column A. Sort in alphabetical order (This is your unique list of "people" for that time period)
3) Use CountIFS to show how many times each initial appears below each instrument

Comment: My apologies! I've rerun the macro twice with only values and I still receive the same error and same results in A column. [Screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/H4F3J9f) .

Comment: The Data should begin from row 3. Rows 1 and 2 are headers.

Comment: Try it now. I've updated the code in my original Answer. Please keep in mind the Data should begin in Row 3. And should be outside a table format for now. Fingers crossed.

Comment: It works! You are amazing! It works! Thank you very much for your time and effort Abdul! You've saved us a lot of tedious work! Thank you once again! Submitting screenshot of its success! [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/8Ns2zTQ)

Comment: Aha I think I'm just as excited as you were. No worries; glad to know it works.